# Retrieving SKU only from datalayer

Tags: javascript, adobe

I'm trying to get the value of SKU in adobe tag manager. here is the chunk of code that the ecommerce site spits out:

```
 digitalData.ecommerce.event = eventType;
          digitalData.ecommerce.step = stepCount;
          digitalData.ecommerce.transactionId = "CA181119-04865001";
          digitalData.ecommerce.transactionTotal = "1159.98";
          digitalData.ecommerce.transactionTax = "0.0";

          digitalData.ecommerce.customerId = "";
          digitalData.ecommerce.customerCity = "";
          digitalData.ecommerce.customerZip = "";
          digitalData.ecommerce.customerBirth = "";
          digitalData.ecommerce.customerGender = "";
          digitalData.ecommerce.transactionShipping = shippingVal;
          digitalData.ecommerce.transactionDiscount = discountVal;


          var transactionProds = {
              "sku": "SM-T280NZKAXAC",
              "name": "Galaxy Tab A (7.0)",
              "category": "",
              "price": "199.99",
              "quantity": "1",
              "discount": "0.0"
          };

          digitalData.ecommerce.transactionProducts.transactionProds;

          var transactionProds = {
              "sku": "SM-G955WZKAXAC",
              "name": "Galaxy S8+",
              "category": "",
              "price": "959.99",
              "quantity": "1",
              "discount": "0.0"
          };
```

I tried this code but its not working:

```
var noOfproducts = [];
var SKU = "";
 for (var i = 0; i < noOfproducts.length; i++) {
  SKU += digitalData.ecommerce.transactionProducts[i].sku + "<br />";
 }
```

Can some one please tell me how to write the proper script to get all the values of SKU from the original code?

Comment: Can you define "not working"? What error messages, log messages, etc. are you receiving?

Answer (score 0):

Actually i figured it out, used this:

```
sku = []
for (i=0; i< digitalData.ecommerce.transactionProducts.length; i++) { 
sku.push(digitalData.ecommerce.transactionProducts[i].sku); 
}
return sku
```